# UnrealEngine4 - Restricting DataTable pointer to only use certain row structure

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

So i have these two structs:

```
USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FLevelMapStruct : public FTableRowBase
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

public:

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
    int32 LocationX;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
    int32 LocationY;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
    TSubclassOf<ATile> TileType;
};

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct FLevelStruct : public FTableRowBase
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

public:

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
    UDataTable* MapTable;
};
```

I want to allow blueprint data table created with row structure `FLevelStruct` to only be able to use data table created with `FLevelMapStruct` row structure in field `MapTable`.

Can someone point me in the right direction about how could i do this?

Edit: the `MapTable` will need to be able to point to blueprint data table

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but can you subclass `UDataTable` for this purpose?

Comment: @Rotem I need it to be blueprintable, and i don't think subclasses of `UDataTable` can be made blueprintable

Comment: Neither are regular data tables. What exactly do you mean by blueprintable?

Comment: @Rotem i kinda managed to get it blueprintable, but that's not really what i wanted. I was thinking that if i could make a blueprint subclass of my subclass of `UDataTable` i could somewhat make it only accept `FLevelMapStruct` in it's Row Struct field in blueprint subclass

Comment: I was suggesting that you make a c++ subclass of `UDataTable` that is hardcoded with your struct.

Comment: @Rotem I tried that, but i have no idea how could i set `RowStruct` member of  `UDataTable` to my struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just hit this exact issue myself and I believe I have the answer (works for me at least with UE 4.26).  Have seen a few posts asking with no answer so figured I should share my solution.

In the `UPROPERTY` macro add `meta=(RequiredAssetDataTags = "RowStructure=*YoureRowTypeHere*")`

So in your example you would have

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, meta=(RequiredAssetDataTags = "RowStructure=LevelMapStruct"))
UDataTable* MapTable;
```

Note that the `F` isn't included in the name of the RowStructure, so `LevelMapStruct` rather than `FLevelMapStruct`

In editor now, your property should only list the tables that use that type.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to make this work inside structs too? In classes it works fine but if I set this meta inside an USTRUCT it gets ignored

Answer (score 4):

For custom Class with Unreal 5.1, I use this :

```
UPROPERTY(meta = (RequiredAssetDataTags = "RowStructure=/Script/MyProject.MyData"))
UDataTable* database = nullptr;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, meta = (RowType = "/Script/MyProject.MyData"))
FDataTableRowHandle rowIntoDatabase;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, meta = (RowType = "/Script/MyProject.MyData"))
TArray<FDataTableRowHandle> someRowIntoDatabase;
```

It's same comment: Note that the `F` isn't included in the name of the RowStructure, so `MyData` rather than `FMyData`

It's work inside USTRUCT, I create my DataTable with it.